# What is the replacement of CryptoConfig class in .NETCore?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, .net-core

Currently i am doing this in my UWP app

```
byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(Password);
byte[] hash = ((HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(bytes);
string hashstring = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
```

I have searched a lot but couldn't find the replacement of CryptoConfig class in .NETCore.

Comment: It's almost always, but not entirely, true that if you're accessing CryptoConfig you're doing something wrong.  The algorithms that have constructors (e.g. HMACSHA256) should be directly constructed, the ones that are abstract (e.g. RSA) should be instantiated by their Create methods. (And while HashAlgorithm is abstract and has a Create method, don't use that one... it's not a specific algorithm, so you don't know what you're getting into)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you don't need `CryptoConfig` at all. You just need [`MD5`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash);
}
```

The `MD5` class is present in netstandard1.3 and higher.

Comment: But this is not giving me the desired result. Is there something else also that i need to use?

Comment: @tushargoyal1309: That suggests you're using expecting the wrong result. That *will* give the right MD5 hash.

Comment: Had to use new UnicodeEncoding() instead of Encoding class. Thanks a ton Jon :)

Comment: @tushargoyal1309: Rather than creating a new instance of `UnicodeEncoding`, you should just use `Encoding.Unicode` - no point in creating a new object each time. (Note that's then *not* what the code you posted from your UWP app does...) I'd also point out that MD5 is a pretty insecure way of hashing passwords.

Comment: Then which algorithm do you suggest?